# Nice Answer or Good Answer?

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges, votes

(I'm guessing this is almost definitely status-bydesign for historical reasons but...)

It seems SimchasTorah got a silver [Good Answer badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/39/good-answer?userid=87) for [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1819/759) which only has 10 votes and a [Good Question badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/41/good-question?userid=87) for the question thereof which only has 13 votes. Don't you need 25 votes for those badges?

Comment: FWIW those badges were awarded on Migration Day.

Comment: @msh210 Were the rules different before migration?

Comment: (Yet another notification I didn't get! I just happened to come across your comment, Double AA.) I don't recall (maybe Isaac Moses does); but it shouldn't matter, should it? What should matter is whether the rues were different just *after* migration than now, and I'm not seeing anything about that on meta.SO.

Comment: @msh210 I don't know how the migration worked. Did badges come along? Were they recalculated? It could very well be that you are right and this is actually a bug.

Comment: @msh210 It seems from [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31/i-see-that-my-reputation-has-migragted-from-mi-yodeya-but-not-all-of-my-badges) that you are right. Maybe this _is_ actually a bug.

Comment: @msh210, I think these badges didn't exist on SE 1.0. Note that the first Nice Answer badges were [awarded](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/45?page=5) at migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rebecca Chernoff](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/415/rebecca-chernoff) looked at the Mi Yodeya database backup and that answer was probably a victim of an [old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67592/how-can-a-post-have-an-overall-score-of-1-with-0-up-and-1-down-votes) that could cause the score to become incorrect.

I have no strong feelings about revoking the badge - if you all would like it removed, I'll be happy to do it.

Comment: Thank you @RebbecaChernoff for checking!

Comment: Informal poll: upvote this comment if you care that the badges be removed...

Comment: ...and upvote this one if you don't particularly care.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible (and I think my recollection in fact is) that in this case, there were 25 votes recorded for each of these posts when we migrated, triggering the badges, but some server process subsequently stripped some of the votes, but not the badges, since the latter, once awarded, are not removed.

Comment: It detected 15 unfair votes?? That sounds extreme. What reasons are there for stripping votes besides creating other users to vote for yourself, or bots?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the specifics of what the server [looks for](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) are secret, known only to SE staff. Note that the server's algorithms' suspicion of invalid votes is [not necessarily](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/535/question-upvotes-lost) identical with an actual occurance of invalid votes.